# Updated application from express 3 to express 4, now req.files is returning undefined

Tags: node.js, express

While trying to update from express 3 to express 4 my file upload route starting returning req.files as undefined. I have installed the middleware as separate dependencies now that they're not included in express and I have stopped using the app.configure() method that was removed. Here is my main server file

```
    // dependencies ==========================================================================

    var express        = require('express');                  // framework
    var mongoose       = require('mongoose');                 // mongo driver
    var morgan         = require('morgan');                   // request logger
    var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
    var methodOverride = require('method-override');
    var fs             = require('fs');
    var app            = express();                           // initialize as 'app'

    // configuration =========================================================================

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/constellates');

    var port = 4000;                                          // set port number for app
    app.use(bodyParser());                                    // pull information from html in POST
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));           // set static files directory
    app.use(morgan('dev'));                                   // log every request to the console
    app.use(methodOverride());                                // simulate PUT and DELETE


    // routes ================================================================================

    require('./routes')(app);                                 // load routing from 'routes.js'

    // start server ==========================================================================

    app.listen(port);                                         // start server listening
    console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port);       // display success message with port number
```

and here's my route that I've simplified for troubleshooting

```
    app.post('/api/upload', function (req, res) {
      console.log(req.files);
    });
```

Nothing has changed on the client side. My best guess is that some change to bodyParser is affecting this but I haven't found anything yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As part of the `3.x` -> `4.x` changes, the middleware for processing `multipart/form-data` request body data was removed from the `bodyParser` middleware, so it only parses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json` request body data.

If you want to use `multipart/form-data` as the request body, you need to use the [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) middleware.